# SQL CASE statement issue

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem of else case in SQL case statement.

In my SQL table column `L_Keyword2` contains below value and is of `varchar` type.

```
YES,
LAND INCLUDED,
N/APPLICABLE,
3,
1.5,
NO,
4.5+,
OTHER,
NULL,
2,
1,
LAND LEASED,
0,
3.5,
N/A,
OE,
4,
2.5,
```

When I use this column in case statement like as

```
SELECT 
    L_Keyword2,
    CASE 
       WHEN class LIKE 'RE_1' THEN L_Keyword2 ELSE 0 END
FROM Mytable
```

This SQL query throws an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.5' to data type int.

Why does this SQL query cause a conversion error? Even I am not done any conversion in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT 
    L_Keyword2,
    CASE 
       WHEN class LIKE 'RE_1' THEN L_Keyword2 ELSE '0' END
FROM Mytable
```

If you want to use `LIKE` put `%` wildcard. Otherwise it is simple comparison (`WHEN class = 'RE_1'`).

Comment: The underscore, `'_'` in `'RE_1'` is a wild card that matches one character. Similar to `'.'` in regular expressions, or `'?'` in DOS/Windows file names.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `CASE` in T-SQL is **not** a statement - it's an **expression**. As such, all the values that it can return from its various `WHEN` clauses have to be of the same **datatype**, and if they're not, then SQL Server has a precedence list ([see the relevant MSDN documentation for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) ) - and on that list, `int` ranges higher than `varchar`

In your case, the `CASE` obviously returns an `int` from the `ELSE` clause, so it is trying to return the value of `L_Keyword2` (from the first `WHEN ... THEN ...` clause) as an `Int` also, and therefore fails.